# rpmbuild Requires(rpmlib) - custom rpm

Tags: linux, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I was trying to build an rpm of some scripts and settings we would to easily distribute internally. I was able to build an RPM just file with a test file and jboss but when doing it with this set of files I am getting a Requires(rpmlib) error (full output below) ; I've tried searching for any missing dependencies but the files in the folders to be placed in the root doesn't require anything. Any suggestions?

rpmbuild -bb siscripts.spec 

Processing files: SIScripts-1-1.noarch
Requires(rpmlib): rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1 rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1 rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
perl(File::stat) perl(HTML::Template) perl(MIME::Lite) perl(Net::Ping) 
perl(String::MkPasswd) perl(Term::ANSIScreen) perl(Term::ReadLine) perl(Unix::PasswdFile) perl(strict)

Checking for unpackaged file(s): /usr/lib/rpm/check-files /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/SIScripts-1-1.x86_64

warning: Could not canonicalize hostname: repo.local

Wrote: /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/noarch/SIScripts-1-1.noarch.rpm

Executing(%clean): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.QUQOX3

+ umask 022

+ cd /root/rpmbuild/BUILD

+ /bin/rm -rf /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/SIScripts-1-1.x86_64

+ exit 0

Comment: You aren't getting an error message. You were just getting a warning. What's in the `Requires:` and `BuildRequires:` of `siscripts.spec` file?

Comment: Nothing actually, since its just dropping files in to a directory I didn't think those two fields were necessary.

Comment: Don't be alarmed. Nothing is wrong with the output. The spec file you wrote has a `Requires:` that required those rpmlib and perl. It successfully built the package.

Comment: Unfortunately when I do try and install the RPM I get the requires errors; I did manually install the required perl modules it requested via cpan; Any other suggestions?

Error: Package: SIScripts-1-1.noarch (/SIScripts-1-1.noarch) Requires: perl(Term::ANSIScreen)

Comment: If you are absolutely certain that you don't want those requires, all you need to do is remove `Requires:` in the spec file and build a new package.

Comment: I am using rpmbuild version 4.11.1 and does not use the "Requires::" in the spec file, still i get the rpmlib error.

Answer (score 0):

The message
     warning: Could not canonicalize hostname: repo.local 
just means that the host name could not be looked up.

RPM adds a tag with the host FQDN and a time stamp to every package.

Simply adding an entry in /etc/hosts for "repo.local" will eliminate
the warning.

All the rpm lib dependencies look correct.